# How to streamline code using for statement when rendering in django's views.py

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using django and the code below works inefficiently. Is there a way to shorten the method of creating and appending a list by using a for statement as in the code below? list is used to create graphs in apex chart javascript.

**[views.py]**

```
annotations = {}
types = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
for type in types:
    annotations[type] = Count('id', filter=Q(type=type))
    annotations[f'r_{type}'] = Count('id', filter=Q(type=type, is_recruiting='Recruiting'))
    annotations[f'N_{type}'] = Count('id', filter=Q(type=type, is_recruiting='Not yet recruiting'))
    annotations[f'H_{type}'] = Count('id', filter=Q(type=type, is_recruiting='Holding'))
    annotations[f'C_{type}'] = Count('id', filter=Q(type=type, is_recruiting='Completed'))
    counts = Research.objects.values('teacher').annotate(**annotations).values('teacher', *annotations.keys())

teacher = [];
A = [];
B= [];
C= [];
D= [];
E= [];
F= [];
r_A = [];
r_B = [];
r_C = [];
r_D = [];
r_E = [];
r_F = [];
...
C_E = [];
C_F = [];
for count in counts:
    teacher.append(str(count['teacher']))
    A.append(str(count['A']))
    B.append(str(count['B']))
    C.append(str(count['C']))
    D.append(str(count['D']))
    E.append(str(count['E']))
    F.append(str(count['F']))
    r_A.append(str(count['r_A']))
    r_B.append(str(count['r_B']))
    r_C.append(str(count['r_C']))
    r_D.append(str(count['r_D']))
    r_E.append(str(count['r_E']))
    r_F.append(str(count['r_F']))
    ...
    C_E.append(str(count['C_E']))
    C_F.append(str(count['C_F']))

return render(request, 'graph.html',
              {
                  'teacher': teacher,
                  'A': A,
                  'B': B,
                  'C': C,
                  'D': D,
                  'E': E,
                  'F': F, 
                  'r_A': r_A,
                  'r_B': r_B,
                  'r_C': r_C,
                  'r_D': r_D,
                  'r_E': r_E,
                  'r_F': r_F,
                  ...
                  'C_E': C_E,
                  'C_F': C_F     
              })
```

**[graph.html]**

```
series: [{% if is_recruiting == 'Recruiting' %}
    {
      name: 'A',
      data: {{ r_A | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      data: {{ r_B | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      data: {{ r_C | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      data: {{ r_D | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'E',
      data: {{ r_E | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'F',
      data: {{ r_F | safe }}
    },{% elif is_recruiting == 'ALL' %}
    {
      name: 'A',
      data: {{ A | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      data: {{ B | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      data: {{ C | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      data: {{ D | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'E',
      data: {{ E | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'F',
      data: {{ F | safe }}
    }, ... {% elif is_recruiting == 'Completed' %}
    {
      name: 'A',
      data: {{ C_A | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      data: {{ C_B | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      data: {{ C_C | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      data: {{ C_D | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'E',
      data: {{ C_E | safe }}
    }, {
      name: 'F',
      data: {{ C_F | safe }}
    },{% endif %}
    ],
```

This is a javascript that creates a graph using apexchart.js.
This part also continues the code with an if statement, so the readability is not good. Is there any way to shorten this part as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
for count in counts:
    teacher.append(str(count['teacher']))
    A.append(str(count['A']))
    B.append(str(count['B']))
    C.append(str(count['C']))
    D.append(str(count['D']))
    E.append(str(count['E']))
    F.append(str(count['F']))
```

could be re-written using a dict rather than multiple lists:

```
count_dict = defaultdict(list)
for type_, count in itertools.product(types, counts):
    count_dict[type_].append(str(count[type_]))
```

(reason it's `type_` and not `type` is because `type` is a reserved word ... just pick another var name, eg. `t` if you don't like the underscore)

Comment: Thank you for answer. It seems that it will take some time for me to understand the code you answered, but when I try it, only the following values ​​are output. What's wrong?   -> Result:  defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 'B': ['3', '1', '5', '3', '0'], 'C': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'D': ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0',], 'E': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 'F': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']})